# Android, ListView and ArrayAdaptater, getView called only once

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to show some data on a listview. My problem is that only one item is shown in my listview.

I've found many topics about here but none helped me.

I've see that the getView() method is called only once (I checked my list, and it's size is 178).

Here is my code:

```
public class RiverListArrayAdaptater extends ArrayAdapter<LinkedList<River>> {

    private Context context;
    private LinkedList<River> list;

    public RiverListArrayAdaptater(Context context,LinkedList<River> list) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_river);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get variables
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cont        ext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_river, parent, false);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textViewValue = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.value);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textViewName.setText(list.get(pos).getName());
        textViewValue.setText(list.get(pos).getDebit());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

My code in the onCreate():

```
    LinkedList<River> list = parser.parse(getter.getData());
            RiverListArrayAdaptater adaptater = new     RiverListArrayAdaptater(this,list);
            adaptater.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adaptater.add(list);
            list1.setAdapter(adaptater);
```

And here my two XML file:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listRiver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/up_or_down"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thx for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override getCount in your ArrayAdapter and return how many items are in the list.

Check the [source for ArrayAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) for more info.

Comment: can you tell me how it worked my situation is same as yours @user1949040

Answer (score 0):

I never used `ArrayAdapter` but I would think that you should derived from `River` instead of `LinkedList<River>` and

```
public class RiverListArrayAdaptater extends ArrayAdapter<LinkedList<River>> {...}
```

should be replaced with:

```
public class RiverListArrayAdaptater extends ArrayAdapter<River> {...}
```

The list is considered as the fundamental object and you end up with a list of `LinkedList` instead of a list of `River`; therefore, you have only one item in your `ListView` because you have only one `LinkedList`.